# how to check if a record exits in one table then it should ignore it in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have two tables as follow in sql

*Branches*

```
ID   | BranchID | GameTypeID | flag
1    | 55       | 111        | 1
2    | 16       | 235        | 0
```

*Games*

```
GameTypeID
123
456
111
235
458
```

what i am trying to achieve is that when Games is loaded it must check if the GameTypeID exits in the branch table for that ID and that the flag is 1. So for example if i pass BranchId 55 then from the Games list gametypeid 111 should be removed giving me the following list

```
Expected Outcome
    Games
    235
    123
    456
    458
```

this is my code

```
GameLevel retVal = new GameLevel(GetGames(gameid, isdateroot, startdate, enddate, iscurrent, isdatesort, requestfrom));
var assignments =GetByBranchId(SessionManager.LoggedBranch.BranchIDb => b.Flag);
if (assignments.Any())
{
    var gameTypes = assignments.Select(x => x.GameTypeId.ToString()).ToList();
    retVal.Rows = retVal.Rows.Where(x => gameTypes.Contains(x.GameTypeID)).ToList();
}
return retVal;
```

so whats happening in the above is that when its passing the BranchID 55 its going and checking the flag but the problem is that when it finds that row its not ignoring the GametypeID 111 it ignores everything else and this is the result i get back

```
*current output*
Games
111
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: you mean like this `select * from Games g inner join Branches b on g.GameTypeID = b.GameTypeID and b.flag = 0`

Comment: No, like select * from Game t where not exists(select 1 from dbo.branch a where a.BranchID='55' and a.GameTypeID='111' and flag='1') but i want this same logic in the code mentioned above

Comment: i am not sure what i did wrong in the above code

Comment: Your query selects the ones which are contained. You should select NOT contained ones. Like -- `.Where(x => !gameTypes.Contains(x.GameTypeID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the issue. I'm going to walk through your code here so, if I make a bad assumption you can correct my

```
//1. This line gets an instance of a List<Games> (or something roughly like that)
GameLevel retVal = new GameLevel(GetGames(gameid, isdateroot, startdate, enddate, iscurrent, isdatesort, requestfrom));
//2. This line gets the GameTypeIds for the flagged Branch
var assignments =GetByBranchId(SessionManager.LoggedBranch.BranchIDb => b.Flag);
//3. self explanatory. 'If there is anything in the assignment variable'
if (assignments.Any())
{
    //4. Get a list of GameTypeId values from assignments
    var gameTypes = assignments.Select(x => x.GameTypeId.ToString()).ToList();

    //5. Here's where I think you went wrong
    //5. This line gets the Games where gameTypes contains the GameTypeId in retVal.
    retVal.Rows = retVal.Rows.Where(x => gameTypes.Contains(x.GameTypeID)).ToList();
}
return retVal;
```

What you want are all the games in 'retVal' that are NOT included in 'gameTypes.GameTypeId' 
and what you are actually returning is the opposite. You are returning all the games in 'retVal' that have a matching GameTypeId in 'gameTypes'

so...all you need to do is the opposite of what you're currently doing
change this line

```
retVal.Rows = retVal.Rows.Where(x => gameTypes.Contains(x.GameTypeID)).ToList();
```

into this

```
retVal.Rows = retVal.Rows.Where(x => !gameTypes.Contains(x.GameTypeID)).ToList();
```

All I did was add the 'not' operator and now you're returning the Games that DON'T match the flagged GameTypeId's